# How to iterate all data SQLite and assign to Hashmap completely?

Tags: android, sqlite, hashmap

In my SQLite actualy there is 375 data, but when I try to iterate that data and assign to hashmap only 226 data successfully assigned, whats wrong with my code below?

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getLanguage() {
    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DB_TABLE
            , null
            , null
            , null
            , null
            , null, _ID + " ASC"
            , null);
    //cursor.moveToFirst();
    System.out.println("Cursor count"+cursor.getCount());
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
        hashMap.put(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LANG)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(STRING)));
    }
    return hashMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have more than one entry with one `KEY_LANG`. You can store list of `STRING` instead of one `STRING` in map value

```
public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getLanguage() {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DB_TABLE,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            _ID + " ASC",
            null);
    //cursor.moveToFirst();
    System.out.println("Cursor count" + cursor.getCount());
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String key = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LANG));
        String value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(STRING));
        if (hashMap.containsKey(key)) {
            hashMap.get(key).add(value);
        } else {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(value);
            hashMap.put(key, list);
        }
    }
    return hashMap;
}
```

Comment: sorry, i don't understand, can you write the correct code ?

Comment: @asqa check this

Comment: thanks @shmakoca , i allready try your code but still same, when reach 225 hashMap.put(key, list) will not execute and jump to return hashmap

Comment: I have already told you that you have duplicated entries with the same language @asqa Check your database